# Pyspark add column based on other column and a running counter

Tags: pyspark

I have data in pyspark dataframe (it is a very big table with 900M rows)

The dataframe contains a column with these values:

```
+---------------+
|prev_display_id|
+---------------+
|           null|
|           null|
|           1062|
|           null|
|           null|
|           null|
|           null|
|       18882624|
|       11381128|
|           null|
|           null|
|           null|
|           null|
|           2779|
|           null|
|           null|
|           null|
|           null|
+---------------+
```

I am trying to generate a new column based on this column, that will look like this:

```
+---------------+------+
|prev_display_id|result|
+---------------+------+
|           null|     0|
|           null|     1|
|           1062|     0|
|           null|     1|
|           null|     2|
|           null|     3|
|           null|     4|
|       18882624|     0|
|       11381128|     0|
|           null|     1|
|           null|     2|
|           null|     3|
|           null|     4|
|           2779|     0|
|           null|     1|
|           null|     2|
|           null|     3|
|           null|     4|
+---------------+------+
```

The function for the new column is something like:

```
new_col = 0 if (prev_display_id!=null) else col = col+1
```

Where col is like a running counter that reset to zero when a non-null value is met.

How can that be done efficiently in pyspark?

### UPDATE

I tried the solution suggested by @anki below. I works great for small datasets, but it generates this error:

```
WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

Unfortunately it seems that for my big dataset it kills the cluster. 
See image below for the error when running on the big dataset with 2 rd5.2xlarge data nodes:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: The issue here is the optimization. I thought about doing in seevral steps perhaps. First, map on the column with a lambda function that associates 0 to not null values and 1 to null values. Then map again on the new column (with 0 and 1) and increase the  values accordingly. You may use the index of each row in doing that. I shall try to see if there is no predefined function who does that.

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand , you can create an id column with `monotonically_increasing_id` and then take sum over the window for cases where `prev_display_id` is not null , then take row number partitioned by that column and minus 1:

```
w = Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())
w1 = F.sum((F.col("prev_display_id").isNotNull()).cast("integer")).over(w)

(df.withColumn("result",F.row_number()
 .over(Window.partitionBy(w1).orderBy(w1))-1).drop("idx")).show()
```

---

```
+---------------+------+
|prev_display_id|result|
+---------------+------+
|           null|     0|
|           null|     1|
|           1062|     0|
|           null|     1|
|           null|     2|
|           null|     3|
|           null|     4|
|       18882624|     0|
|       11381128|     0|
|           null|     1|
|           null|     2|
|           null|     3|
|           null|     4|
|           2779|     0|
|           null|     1|
|           null|     2|
|           null|     3|
|           null|     4|
+---------------+------+
```

Comment: Nice approach of partitioning on newly created window..i missed that in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can get this by running the following command:

```
window = Window.orderBy(f.monotonically_increasing_id())
df.withColumn('row',f.row_number().over(window))\
.withColumn('ne',f.when(f.col('consumer_id').isNotNull(),f.col('row')))\
.withColumn('result',f.when(f.col('ne').isNull(),f.col('row')-f.when(f.last('ne',ignorenulls=True)\
.over(window).isNull(),1).otherwise(f.last('ne',ignorenulls=True).over(window))).otherwise(0))\
.drop('row','ne').show()

+-----------+------+
|consumer_id|result|
+-----------+------+
|       null|     0|
|       null|     1|
|       null|     2|
|         11|     0|
|         11|     0|
|       null|     1|
|       null|     2|
|         12|     0|
|         12|     0|
+-----------+------+
```